# Python - converting a list of tuples to a list of strings

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'the'), ('the', 'first'), ('first', 'document'), ('document', '.')]
```

What is the most pythonic and efficient way to convert into this where each token is separated by a space:

```
['this is', 'is the', 'the first', 'first document', 'document .']
```

Comment: I have added an answer that avoid using `%s`, for version 3.6+, it uses an f-string, and for previous versions it uses `str.format`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Very simple:

```
[ "%s %s" % x for x in l ]
```

Comment: `[("%s "*len(x)%x).strip() for x in l]`  if you dont know how long each tuple is ... in the example its 2...but if one had 3 entries or someat this would account for that

Comment: @JoranBeasley no, you'd just use `" ".join` for that.

Comment: @Julian yeah your right ... brain fart `[" ".join(x) for x in l]`

Comment: @Julian: Yes I agree `' '.join` deals with that quite nicely. See my answer.

Comment: This works only for 2-tuples. It'll be difficult to extend this to n-tuples for large n. `' '.join(tup)` would be the best way to do it

Answer (score 9):

Using `map()` and `join()`:

```
tuple_list = [('this', 'is'), ('is', 'the'), ('the', 'first'), ('first', 'document'), ('document', '.')]

string_list = map(' '.join, tuple_list)
```

As inspectorG4dget pointed out, list comprehensions are the most pythonic way of doing this:

```
string_list = [' '.join(item) for item in tuple_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
>>> l=[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'the'), ('the', 'first'), 
('first', 'document'), ('document', '.')]
>>> ['{} {}'.format(x,y) for x,y in l]
['this is', 'is the', 'the first', 'first document', 'document .']
```

If your tuples are variable length (or not even), you can also do this:

```
>>> [('{} '*len(t)).format(*t).strip() for t in [('1',),('1','2'),('1','2','3')]]
['1', '1 2', '1 2 3']   #etc
```

Or, probably best still:

```
>>> [' '.join(t) for t in [('1',),('1','2'),('1','2','3'),('1','2','3','4')]]
['1', '1 2', '1 2 3', '1 2 3 4']
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you avoid using `%s`. Starting Python 3.6, [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) were added, so you can take advantage of this feature as follows:

```
[f'{" ".join(e)}' for e in l]
```

If you are using a previous version of Python 3.6, you can also avoid using `%s` by employing the `format` function as follows:

```
print(['{joined}'.format(joined=' '.join(e)) for e in l]) # before Python 3.6
```

**Alternative:**

Assuming you have 2 elements in each tuple, you can use the following:

```py
# Python 3.6+
[f'{first} {second}' for first, second in l]

# Before Python 3.6
['{first} {second}'.format(first=first, second=second) for first, second in l]
```

Comment: `[f’{} {}’ for *x in l] ` would be even better

Comment: @Orbital, I updated my answer. What you suggested didn't work, but I get you want me to make the answer more generic.

Comment: Oops sorry, I couldn’t test it. I assumed it would work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is:

You can use ***list comprehension + join()***

```
li = [('this', 'is'), ('is', 'the'), ('the', 'first'), ('first', 'document'), ('document', '.')]
```

all you need to do is:

```
[' '.join(x) for x in li]
```

You can also use ***map() + join()***

```
list(map(' '.join, li))
```

result :

```
['this is', 'is the', 'the first', 'first document', 'document .']
```